# LIBSVM usage error

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, svm, libsvm

While using the LIBSVM library on ubuntu platform, the following is the output i get. Please guide me on the course of action:

command issued:

```
./svm-scale -u 1 -l -1 -s parameters.txt negativeSet > negativeSet.scaled
./svm-scale -u 1 -l -1 -r parameters.txt positiveSet > positiveSet.scaled
cat negativeSet.scaled > trainingSet.scaled
cat positiveSet.scaled >> trainingSet.scaled 
./svm-train -t 1 -s 1 trainingSet.scaled
```

and

```
./svm-train trainingSet.scaled
```

output observed:

```
optimization finished, #iter = 1
obj = nan, rho = nan
nSV = 0, nBSV = 0
Total nSV = 0
```

I tried using RBF kernel with various parameters and still the problem persist.
My guess is that the problem is with the scaled file, but i cant figure out what is the problem.
Appreciate your early help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tweak the parameters (C, kernel, etc),  since it is very unlikely that you are going to have a functional model by  using the default values.

This guide might be helpful: http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/guide/guide.pdf

Comment: I tried using RBF kernel with various parameters and still the problem persist.

Comment: Thanks i tried this again, the problem was that my negative data set was extremely large and it was overwhelming the positive data set. Thanks for the reply